# Use remote and local images together with next/image

Tags: next.js

I am trying to use `next/image` to load local images as well as remote images. I have my local images in `public/assets/images` and remote images in AWS S3. I want to use a placeholder image (from local) before uploading the image, and then after the upload, replace it with the remote image.

I have added `domains` in my `next.config.js`:

```
const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins')
const nextTranslate = require('next-translate')

const nextConfig = {
  ...
  images: {
    domains: ['xxx.amazonaws.com'],
  },
  ...
}
module.exports = withPlugins([nextTranslate], nextConfig)
```

But still, it proxies it with `localhost` and returns `The requested resource isn't a valid image.`

I tried adding `path` and `loader` along with `domains` in the config, but then it loads all the images from the given path, be it remote or local.

I can use the `img` tag for it but I wish to use next/image for image optimization. Is it possible?

Comment: I had a similar issue and managed to solve it [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70447510/10984558).

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem and this is how I solved it. In your project's `next.config.js` file, add the list of domains where your site may be pulling images from. This would include `localhost`, the domain your site is on when deployed, and an external site. Then set the `loader` to `custom`.

```
// next.config.js

module.exports = {
  images: {
    domains: ['localhost', 'yourdomain.com', 'externaldomain.com'],
    loader: 'custom'
  }
}
```

Then in your code, for each image make sure you set the loader attribute and the correct src. Then for your local images set up your custom loader this way.

```
<Image loader={({src}) => src} src="/logo.png" layout="fill" />
```

Thank you to Hughes' [above comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67985068/use-remote-and-local-images-together-with-next-image#comment124530002_67985068) and the [issue they linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70429040/getting-public-image-asset-in-next-js-project-folder-when-loader-configuration-p) for helping me figure this out.