# Getting public image asset in Next.js project folder when loader configuration path is set

Tags: reactjs, next.js

### Context

I have started a Next.js project that needs to get image assets from two different sources:

1. In the local public folder of the repository: `<Image src="/logo.png" width={50} height={50} alt='Logo' layout="fixed"/>`
2. Assets from a cloud provider ([Cloudinary](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_transformations#transformation_url_structure)): `<Image src="<transformations>/<version>/<public_id>.jpg" width={400} height={400} alt='Planning garden image'/>`

### The Problem

When setting the images path in the `next.config.js` file, images meant to load from the public file now point to Cloudinary.

The image loader path is set [in the Next.js configuration file](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#loader-configuration):

```js
// next.config.js

module.exports = {
  images: {
    loader: 'cloudinary',
    path: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/<cloud_name>/image/upload',
  },
}
```

This means that the 1. above also uses relative URLs for the Image src and prepends it with the path in the config folder. This is incorrect for images stored in the public folder - which would be the default path if the configuration for Cloudinary were not set.

Can I have image paths coming from different sources depending on the context in which I'm using them. I don't want to put all the images on Cloudinary. I want 1 to still come from the public folder.

Comment: you can import the local images like import logo from "./logo.png". here is the link from next https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/image-optimization
Also, try use loader prop in <Image />to override the one defined in next.config.js
<Image loader="./" src="logo.png" layout="fill" />
https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#configuration-options

Comment: Unfortunately neither of these works. Importing the logo from `./logo.png` just adds that to the end of the image config path. Specifying the loader like that doesn't work, it expects a function; when giving it a function that returns that, it doesn't work. Maybe if this could somehow plug into Next.js's ordinary loader function, but I don't know what that would look like.

Comment: Just found this unanswered question which is similar to mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67985068/use-remote-and-local-images-together-with-next-image

Comment: <Image loader={({src})=>`/${src}``} src="logo.png" layout="fill" />

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key bit of information is: "Loaders can be defined per-image, or at the application level."

When the loader configuration is set at the application level so that cloud-based image optimisation can be used, to get local images working override their loader configuration.

As Jerry [showed how to do in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70429040/getting-public-image-asset-in-next-js-project-folder-when-loader-configuration-p?noredirect=1#comment124521696_70429040): `<Image loader={({src})=> src} src="/logo.png" layout="fill" />`