# How to use next/image show image under project folder with Next.js?

Tags: image, next.js

I want to create a component use `next/image` show a image like

```
import React from "react";
import Image from "next/image";

type ThumbnailType = {
  image: string;
  alt: string;
  width: string;
  height: string;
};

export const Thumbnail: React.FC<ThumbnailType> = ({
  image,
  alt,
  width,
  height,
}) => {
  return <Image src={image} alt={alt} width={width} height={height} />;
};
```

When use this component in one page:

```
import type { NextPage } from "next";
import {
  Thumbnail,
} from "~/components";

const Home: NextPage = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Thumbnail
        image="/src/public/product.png"
        alt="nice"
        width="100"
        height="100"
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

The `product.png` image is under the `src/public` folder. But from browser got this src:

> f_auto,c_limit,w_384,q_auto/src/public/product.png

Why?

Comment: did your public folder path is `your_nextjs_project/src/public`?

Comment: @iamhuynq Yes. The path is right. Even I tried to set `image="https://1000logos.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Apple-Logo.png"` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put [public folder](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving) in the root directory, not in `src` folder

```
your_nextjs_project/public

<Thumbnail
    image="/product.png"
    alt="nice"
    width="100"
    height="100"
/>
```

Comment: I tried it but still got this src: `f_auto,c_limit,w_384,q_auto/public/product.png`. So the image didn't been displayed.

Comment: @AlpinCleopatra I've updated answer, can you try?

Comment: Thank you. I tried, but still doesn't work. It always showed the prefix `f_auto,c_limit,w_384,q_auto`. I don't know where it has been generated.

Comment: if you use normal image <img/> , do it work?

Comment: Yes, it works if use <img/>.

Comment: One config I set in the `next.config.js` is `images: { loader: "cloudinary", path: "", }`. Does it generated the unused prefix? I think that's for build resource but now I'm using `npm run dev` without build the images.

Comment: @AlpinCleopatra oh, i think that is problem, please check [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70429040/getting-public-image-asset-in-next-js-project-folder-when-loader-configuration-p?noredirect=1#comment124521696_70429040)

Comment: Thank you! After I added `loader={({src})=> src}` it works!